# Wordpress child theme files behavior

Tags: css, wordpress

In a child theme, I have an `app.css` file containing code modifications. Meanwhile, a theme update was released including a new `app.css`. In these conditions, if I update the main theme, in browser will be still visible my `app.css`ignoring the update?

In other words, interesting to know if the overriding proccess is applied to files or in depth between the code lines of the same files? Thanks

Comment: very unclear question, but if your css is in your child theme and imports the parent app.css, its changes will be reflected as much as they have not been redefined in the child theme. Actually go look at the stylesheets and check the rendering in the browser (inspect element) to see how they apply.

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding, perhaps it's my language. I'll reformulate the question in other way, to clarify: what sense will have a main theme update, (that contain new modified files like `app.css`, `app.min.js`, `script-calls.php`) as long as I've made some changes in these files but in Child theme?

Comment: Your child theme files are not touched, your theme files are all updated to whatever the author is supplying. If the theme allowed for child theme js files, they will continue to use the childthemes if the theme continues to allow it. There is always the risk something will no longer be compatable, but in general theme authors dont make drastic changes. Why dont you copy the site to a local dev and try updating?

Comment: I got it. thanks, It's a good idea.